# overplot multiple sets of data with hexbin

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, seaborn

I am doing some KMeans clustering on a large and really dense data set and I am trying to figure out the best way to visualize the clusters.

In 2D, it looks like [hexbin](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hexbin#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) would do a good job but I am unable to overplot the clusters on the same figure. I want to use [hexbin](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hexbin#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) on each of the clusters separately with a different color map for each but for some reason this does not seem to work.
The image shows what I get when I try to plot a second and third sets of data.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?
[image]

After some fiddling, I was able to make this with [Seaborn's kdeplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried setting `alpha` for each hexbin? Can you make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example?

Comment: @Labibah This seems interesting to address, same question:  Can you make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example?

Comment: I agree with @farenorth.  Can you post/create a fake dataset with random numbers (formatted how it is after clustering is done) along with your plotting code.  It will be a lot faster for others to play with...

Comment: Also if your data is *really* dense, usually for plotting/visualizing purposes it is ok to down sample your data before plotting.  This will plot faster and any alpha transparencies you have will not get stacked together so much that they end up making solid colors...

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think your solution from kdeplot is quite good (although I would work a bit on the parts were clusters intercept). In any case as response to your question you can provide a minimum count to hexbin (leaving all empty cells as transparent). Here's a small function to produce random clusters for anyone that might want to make some experiments (in the comments your question seemed to build a lot of interest from users, fell free to use it):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Building random clusters
def cluster(number):
    def clusterAroundX(a,b,number):
        x = np.random.normal(size=(number,))
        return (x-x.min())*(b-a)/(x.max()-x.min())+a
    def clusterAroundY(x,m,b):
        y = x.copy()
        half   = (x.max()-x.min())/2
        middle = half+x.min()
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            std = (x.max()-x.min())/(2+10*(np.abs(middle-x[i])/half))
            y[i] = np.random.normal(x[i]*m+b,std)
        return y + np.abs(y.min())
    m,b = np.random.randint(-700,700)/100,np.random.randint(0,50)
    print(m,b)
    f = np.random.randint(0,30)
    l = f + np.random.randint(10,50)
    x = clusterAroundX(f,l,number)
    y = clusterAroundY(x,m,b)
    return x,y
```

, using this code I've produced a few cluster a plotted them with scatterplot (I usually use this for my own cluster analysis, but I guess I should take a look into seaborn), hexbin, imshow (change for pcolormesh for more control) and contourf:

```
clusters = 5
samples  = 300
xs,ys = [],[]
for i in range(clusters):
    x,y = cluster(samples)
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)

# SCATTERPLOT
alpha = 1
for i in range(clusters):
    x,y = xs[i],ys[i]
    color = (np.random.randint(0,255)/255,np.random.randint(0,255)/255,np.random.randint(0,255)/255)
    plt.scatter(x,y,c = color,s=90,alpha=alpha)
plt.show()

# HEXBIN
# Hexbin seems a bad choice because I think you cant control the size of the hexagons.
alpha = 1
cmaps = ['Reds','Blues','Purples','Oranges','Greys']
for i in range(clusters):
    x,y = xs[i],ys[i]
    plt.hexbin(x,y,gridsize=20,cmap=cmaps.pop(),mincnt=1)
plt.show()

# IMSHOW
alpha = 1
cmaps = ['Reds','Blues','Purples','Oranges','Greys']
xmin,xmax = min([i.min() for i in xs]), max([i.max() for i in xs])
ymin,ymax = min([i.min() for i in ys]), max([i.max() for i in ys])
nums = 30
xsize,ysize  = (xmax-xmin)/nums,(ymax-ymin)/nums
im = [np.zeros((nums+1,nums+1)) for i in range(len(xs))]
def addIm(im,x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        im[i,j] = im[i,j]+1
    return im
for i in range(len(xs)):
    xo,yo = np.int_((xs[i]-xmin)/xsize),np.int_((ys[i]-ymin)/ysize)
    #im[i][xo,yo] = im[i][xo,yo]+1
    im[i] = addIm(im[i],xo,yo)
    im[i] = np.ma.masked_array(im[i],mask=(im[i]==0))
for i in range(clusters):
    # REPLACE BY pcolormesh if you need more control over image locations.
    plt.imshow(im[i].T,origin='lower',interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmaps.pop())
plt.show()

# CONTOURF
cmaps = ['Reds','Blues','Purples','Oranges','Greys']
for i in range(clusters):
    # REPLACE BY pcolormesh if you need more control over image locations.
    plt.contourf(im[i].T,origin='lower',interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmaps.pop())
plt.show()
```

, the result are the folloing:

[image: scatterplot clusters]

[image: hexbin clusters]

[image: imshow clusters]

[image: countourf clusters]